# segmentation fault (core dumped) in reading a text file

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm working on a model to solve with cplex. I have a cpp file and loadInstance.hpp to run my code with different instances. I compile my code successfully and make the makefile. But when I try to run. I have this error : segment fault (core dumped). It cant read my text file!!!! here is my loadeInstance.hpp :

```
int loadInstance(char* instances)
{
    char values[100];
    cout << "Started loading the instance... ";
    // open the file
  
    ifstream file(instances);
    ofstream TrafficData("Traffic_Read.txt");
    ofstream AssignCostData("AssignCost_Read.txt");
    ofstream LinkCostData("LinkCost_Read.txt");
    ofstream LinkCapacityData("LinkCapacity_Read.txt");
    ofstream HubCapacityData("HubCapacity_Read.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
    // start loading the data
 // read the first line on the text file

    while(file >> V)
    {
    cout << V ;
    
    //t[i][j] 
    t = new int* [V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        t[i] = new int [V+1];
       
    }

    //C[i][k] 
    C = new int* [V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        C[i] = new int [V];
   
    }

    //R[k][l] 
    R = new int* [V];
    for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
    {
        R[k] = new int [V];
  
    }

  // Qb[k][l]
    Qb = new int* [V];
    for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
    {
        Qb[k] = new int [V];

    }

    // Qh[k]
    Qh = new int [V];

    //Read the instance
    //Read traffic between i and j
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < V; ++j)
        {
            file >> t[i][j];
            TrafficData << "t[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << t[i][j] << endl;
        }
    //Read Cost from i and k
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
        {
            file >> C[i][k];
            AssignCostData << "C[" << i << "][" << k << "]=" << C[i][k] << endl;
        }
    //Read Cost of each link on the edge connecting hubs k and l

    for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
        for (int l = 0; l < V; ++l)
        {
            file >> R[k][l];
            LinkCostData << "R[" << k << "][" << l << "]=" << R[k][l] << endl;
        }
    //Read Maximum capacity of backbone edge

    for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
        for (int l = 0; l < V; ++l)
        {
            file >> Qb[k][l];
            LinkCapacityData << "Qb[" << k << "][" << l << "]=" << Qb[k][l] << endl;
        }

    //Read Maximum capacity of each hub
    for (int k = 0; k < V; ++k)
        {
            file >> Qh[k];
            HubCapacityData << "Qh[" << k << "]=" << Qb[k] << endl;
        }
        return (1);
    }
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "Error opening data file."<< instances << endl;
        return (0);
    }
    
}
```

and here is my text file :

```
10

0   6469    7629    20036   4690    6194    11688   2243    8857    7248    
6469    0   12999   13692   3322    5576    3878    3202    6699    4198    
7629    12999   0   35135   5956    14121   5951    5768    16578   4242    
20036   13692   35135   0   19094   35119   21423   27342   51341   15826   
4690    3322    5956    19094   0   7284    3102    1562    7180    1917    
6194    5576    14121   35119   7284    0   5023    3512    10419   3543    
11688   3878    5951    21423   3102    5023    0   11557   6479    34261   
2243    3202    5768    27342   1562    3512    11557   0   5615    7095    
8857    6699    16578   51341   7180    10419   6479    5615    0   4448    
7248    4198    4242    15826   1917    3543    34261   7095    4448    0   

26304   53  74  17  47  54  36  323 40  57  
53  68268   17  26  77  33  185 281 36  177 
74  17  26029   14  75  23  155 183 22  226 
17  26  14  150779  8   5   22  19  2   35  
47  77  75  8   27293   18  153 414 19  275 
54  33  23  5   18  30202   120 207 5   187 
36  185 155 22  153 120 22009   34  91  3   
323 281 183 19  414 207 34  24301   122 73  
40  36  22  2   19  5   91  122 47326   147 
57  177 226 35  275 187 3   73  147 42040   

0   230 378 239 149 224 283 483 241 278 
230 0   148 245 171 125 478 600 162 496 
378 148 0   343 300 222 616 706 248 641 
239 245 343 0   102 124 316 362 94  372 
149 171 300 102 0   90  317 432 95  352 
224 125 222 124 90  0   404 486 37  442 
283 478 616 316 317 404 0   265 393 88  
483 600 706 362 432 486 265 0   457 350 
241 162 248 94  95  37  393 457 0   438 
278 496 641 372 352 442 88  350 438 0   


11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988
11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988  11988

478016 478016 478016 478016 478016 478016 478016 478016 478016 478016
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= V; ++i)` is wrong. The first index is `0` and the last index is `V-1`, arrays use 0-based indices. Change it to `for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)`

Comment: and consider to use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, *watching* the values in variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: I recommend properly *indenting* your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Where is `V` defined?

Comment: The rare off-by-2 error. If `V` is 10, your code will try to access the twelfth entry in an array with only ten entries.

Comment: I changed it to  for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)  but I have had already the segmentation fault error

Comment: I defined V as a global variable in my header file

Comment: why does each loop use different names for the loop variables? You use `i,j`, then `i,k` then `k,l`. I find this a little confusing, why not use `i` and `j` always?

Comment: Because I have a lot of noes (V= number of nodes) and I want to choose hub nodes between them (i , j are terminal nodes, not Hub) and (k, l are Hub nodes)